# PowerShell : check if FTP Service and/or SMTP Service and IIS Service is installed or not

Tags: powershell

I want to check status of FTP / SMTP and IIS service  for all my machines in my environment. We have mixed OSes such as 2008 ,2012R2 ,2016 and 2019.

How can we tuning my script ?

Here is my script:

```
    $w3svc = get-service w3svc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $smtpsvc = get-service smtpsvc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $ftpsvc = get-service ftpsvc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


If (($w3svc -eq $null) -and (($ftpsvc -eq $null) -and ($smtpsvc -eq $null))) {
        
        Write-Host "IIS is not installed , FTP is not installed , SMTP is not installed $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"



    }

Elseif  (($w3svc -ne $null) -and (($ftpsvc -eq $null) -and ($smtpsvc -eq $null)))

{
   Write-Host "IIS installed $($w3svc.status) , FTP is not installed , SMTP is not installed $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}

Elseif  (($w3svc -ne $null) -and (($ftpsvc -ne $null) -and ($smtpsvc -ne $null)))

{
   Write-Host "IIS installed $($w3svc.status) , FTP installed $($ftpsvc.status) , SMTP installed $($smtpsvc.status) $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}


Elseif  (($w3svc -ne $null) -and (($ftpsvc -eq $null) -and ($smtpsvc -ne $null)))

{
   Write-Host "IIS installed $($w3svc.status), FTP is not installed , SMTP installed $($smtpsvc.status) $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}


Elseif  (($w3svc -ne $null) -and (($ftpsvc -ne $null) -and ($smtpsvc -eq $null)))

{


   Write-Host "IIS installed $($w3svc.status) , FTP installed $($ftpsvc.status) , SMTP is not installed $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}


Elseif  (($w3svc -eq $null) -and (($ftpsvc -ne $null) -and ($smtpsvc -ne $null)))

{
   Write-Host "IIS is not installed , FTP installed $($ftpsvc.status) , SMTP installed $($smtpsvc.status) $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}



Elseif (($w3svc -eq $null) -and (($ftpsvc -eq $null) -and ($smtpsvc -ne $null)))

{
   Write-Host "IIS is not installed , FTP is not installed , SMTP installed $($smtpsvc.status) $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}



Elseif  (($w3svc -eq $null) -and (($ftpsvc -ne $null) -and ($smtpsvc -eq $null)))

{
   Write-Host "IIS is not installed , FTP  installed $($ftpsvc.status) , SMTP is not installed $($(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption)"
}
```

Comment: At a glance it looks like it should work, though it's not the most efficient code. Are you instead looking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of computernames to test, you could do:

```
$result = foreach ($machine in $listOfComputers) {
    'w3svc', 'smtpsvc', 'ftpsvc' | ForEach-Object {
        $svc = Get-Service -Name $_ -ComputerName $machine -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $machine
            ServiceName  = $_
            IsInstalled  = [bool]($svc)
            DisplayName  = if ($svc) {$svc.DisplayName} else {'Not available'}
            Status       = if ($svc) {$svc.Status} else {'Not available'}
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or use Out-GridView

# save to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\To\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output something like:

```
ComputerName ServiceName IsInstalled DisplayName                              Status
------------ ----------- ----------- -----------                              ------
Server01     w3svc              True World Wide Web Publishing-service       Running
Server01     smtpsvc           False Not available                     Not available
Server01     ftpsvc            False Not available                     Not available
Server02     w3svc              True World Wide Web Publishing-service       Running
Server02     smtpsvc           False Not available                     Not available
Server02     ftpsvc            False Not available                     Not available
```

<sup>I don't have such a variety of OSes to test..</sup>